# How can I list sequentially the x and y axis on chart?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, finance

I have a dataframe and I want to show them on graph. When I start my code, the `x` and `y` axis are non-sequential. How can I solve it? Also I give a example graph on picture. First image is mine, the second one is what I want.

This is my code:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
import datetime as dt #date analyse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd #read file

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)
tarih="01-01-2021"
tarih2="20-06-2021"
start=dt.datetime.strptime(tarih, '%d-%m-%Y')
end=dt.datetime.strptime(tarih2, '%d-%m-%Y')
fg=pd.DataFrame()
liste=[]
tarih=[]
for dt in daterange(start, end):
    dates=dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    with open("fng_value.txt", "r") as filestream:
            for line in filestream:
                date = line.split(",")[0]
                if dates == date:
                    fng_value=line.split(",")[1]
                    liste.append(fng_value)
                    tarih.append(dates)
fg['date']=tarih
fg['fg_value']=liste
print(fg.head())
plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.plot(fg.date,fg.fg_value)
plt.title('Fear&Greed Index')
plt.ylabel('Fear&Greed Data')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

This is my graph:

[image: current graph]

This is the graph that I want:

[image: desired graph]

Comment: looks like the `x` axis and `y` axis are sequential on the graph.

Comment: No i editted the question to be more understandable

Comment: looks like you're plotting strings and not dates

Comment: how can i solve it? Also why the x axis is not sequantially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Line plot with datetime x axis

So it appears this code is opening a text file, adding values to either a list of dates or a list of values, and then making a pandas dataframe with those lists. Finally, it plots the date vs values with a line plot.

A few changes should help your graph look a lot better. A lot of this is very basic, and I'd recommend reviewing some matplotlib tutorials. The Real Python [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/) is a good starting place in my opinion.

Fix the y axis limit:

```
plt.set_ylim(0, 100)
```

Use a x axis locator from [mdates](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) to find better spaced x label locations, it depends on your time range, but I made some data and used day locator.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
```

Use a scatter plot to add data points as on the linked graph

```
plt.scatter(x, y ... )
```

Add a grid

```
plt.grid(axis='both', color='gray', alpha=0.5)
```

Rotate the x tick labels

```
plt.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
```

I simulated some data and plotted it to look like the plot you linked, this may be helpful for you to work from.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))

x = pd.date_range(start='june 26th 2021', end='july 25th 2021')
rng = np.random.default_rng()
y = rng.integers(low=15, high=25, size=len(x))

ax.plot(x, y, color='gray', linewidth=2)
ax.scatter(x, y, color='gray')

ax.set_ylim(0,100)
ax.grid(axis='both', color='gray', alpha=0.5)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,101, 10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
ax.set_xlim(min(x), max(x))
```